# Can I setup the Security Kit module via Drush?

Tags: 8, drush

Does a Drush command exist which I can use to setup the [Security Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/seckit) module? Something like this command:

`drush seckit --img-src:self,unsafe-inline`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could update the Security Kit settings via the `config-set` command:

```
drush config-set seckit.settings seckit_xss.csp.img-src "'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
```

You can find the available configuration keys by looking at Security Kit's  default configuration file, `config/install/seckit.settings.yml`, or you can view your site's current settings through the config export page.